# Best practice to return a vector for nested loop in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I would like to return a vector of pointers to vectors from a class member function.
The function will be called from a nested loop, requesting the vector (and processing it's elements) million times, so unnecessary (re)allocations should be avoided.

[Bjarne Stroustrup recommends returning collections by value](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style), due to C++11 move semantics. However it seems to me that the second approach (doStuff2) is better in my case, since it supports vector reuse. Any suggestions?

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
    typedef std::vector<T> TVec;
    std::vector<TVec> m_items;

public:

    size_t getIndex(size_t i, size_t j);

    std::vector<TVec*> doStuff(float x, float y)
    {
        // calculate n, i0, i1, j0, j1 (by x and y)
        // ...

        std::vector<TVec*> vec;
        vec.reserve(n);

        for (size_t i = i0; i<i1; i++)
            for (size_t j = j0; j<j1; j++)
                vec.push_back(&m_items[getIndex(i, j)]);

        return vec;
    }

    void doStuff2(float x, float y, std::vector<TVec*> &vec)
    {
        // calculate n, i0, i1, j0, j1 (by x and y)
        // ...

        vec.clear();
        vec.reserve(n);

        for (size_t i = i0; i<i1; i++)
            for (size_t j = j0; j<j1; j++)
                vec.push_back(&m_items[getIndex(i, j)]);
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, in you case I think `doStuff2()` is better.

Comment: It depends what you are doing. If you really need to minimize dynamic memory allocations, reusing vectors by passing by reference can be faster.

Comment: @NeilKirk @Mine Shouldn't RVO kick-in for the first case (`doStuff`)? If so, the temporary will be completely eliminated. If not, the variable will just be moved. It seems to me like the interface of the second case is just unnecessarily awkward.

Comment: @JiříPospíšil What if you call the function several times in a row? The first will perform at least one vector allocation each.

Comment: @NeilKirk Right, I should have read the question text more carefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However it seems to me that the second approach (doStuff2) is better in my case, since it supports vector reuse. Any suggestions?

The second option (`doStuff2`) is better than the first, because it avoids reallocating the vector. That said, you should (probably) consider using a visitor pattern:

Your code (if I understood you correctly):

```
// "function will be called from a nested loop, requesting the vector
// (and processing it's elements) million times, so unnecessary
// (re)allocations should be avoided."
void yourCientCode()
{
    std::vector<TVec*> vec;
    for(auto x: ???) for(auto y: ???) // nested loop (a million(?) times)
    {
        A::doStuff2(x, y, vec);
        performClientComputation(vec);
    }
}
```

Alternative code:

```
// "function will be called from a nested loop, requesting the vector
// (and processing it's elements) million times, so unnecessary
// (re)allocations should be avoided."
void yourCientCode()
{
    for(auto x: ???) for(auto y: ???) // nested loop
    {
        A::doStuff3(x, y, performClientComputation); // computation function should
                                                     // be injected as a visitor
    }
}
```

This way, no vector is returned. Client code doesn't have to "get vector then apply computation", but "apply computation on elements satisfying *whatever* conditions" (see Demeter's Law).

Having a vector (or not) becomes an internal implementation detail (as far as client code is concerned) and can be optimized later, without altering client code at all).

Comment: It's pseudocode. OP said "function will be called from a nested loop", so I wrote a nested loop. The question marks represent the fact that I don't know (or care) what should go there; It's just a "nested loop".

Comment: Ok I think the part that confused me was the extra : in your first for loop :)